# Error No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111 con spring boot

Tags: angular, postgresql, spring, spring-boot

estoy haciendo una funcion en postgresql con spring boot y me devuelve este error:

> "error": "No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111"

este es la funcion:

```
    create or replace function eliminar_fechastomadas(id_res numeric,id_hrs numeric,fd Date) returns void as $$
begin
DELETE FROM public.reserva_hora
WHERE reserva_id=id_res and fecha_dia=fd and hora_id=id_hrs;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

esta es donde llamo la query en spring boot:

```
@Modifying
@Query(value= "select eliminar_fechastomadas(?1,?2,?3)",nativeQuery = true  )
public List<Object> eliminar_fechastomadas(Long id_res,Long id_hrs,Date fd);

public List<Object> eliminar_fechastomadas(String id_res,String id_hrs,Date fd);

@Override
public List<Object> eliminar_fechastomadas(String id_res,String id_hrs,Date fd) {
    long id=Long.parseLong(id_res);
    long id2=Long.parseLong(id_hrs);
    return reservaDao.eliminar_fechastomadas(id,id2,fd);
}
```

Y esto es el controller:

```
 @GetMapping("/reservahoras/reservahoradia/{id_res}/{id_hrs}/{fd}")
 public ResponseEntity<?> eliminar_fechastomadas(@PathVariable String id_res,@PathVariable String  id_hrs,@PathVariable String fd) throws ParseException {

    Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(fd);
    
    List<Object> reservahora = null;

    try {
        reservahora = reservaService.eliminar_fechastomadas(id_res,id_hrs,date);
    } catch (DataAccessException e) {
        response.put("mensaje", "Error al ejecutar procedimiento almacenado en la base de datos");
        response.put("error", e.getMessage().concat(": ").concat(e.getMostSpecificCause().getMessage()));
        return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(response, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

    return new ResponseEntity <List<Object>>(reservahora, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siguiendo las respuestas a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557957/jpa-hibernate-call-postgres-function-void-return-mappingexception), tienes algunas opciones, todas relacionadas con que Hibernate no funciona bien usando funciones en la BD que no retornan nada.

- Puedes entregar el llamado a la función entre comillas

```
SELECT \"eliminar_fechastomadas\"()
```

- Puedes hacer un cast de la respuesta de la función

```
SELECT cast(eliminar_fechastomadas() as text)
```

- Cambiar la función PostgreSQL para que retorne un valor cualquiera, número o texto, que definas.

Comment: me funciono perfecto muchas gracias